# Confused with uni -direction Mapping and Bidirection Mapping in hibernate spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, data-modeling

I am getting a bit confused with uni-direction mapping and bir-direction mapping.

Suppose i have

`class Organisation`

That has `many to many` association with `country`.

So a country can have many organisations and organisation can belong to many countries

Now this should be uni-direction or bidirection from ORM point of view.

Because i want that when i create organisation. It should have select box for selecting country

But when i create country , then it should not always ask me to select organisation. But i do need to get the list of organisations in particular country.

So what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it seems to be that you quite often need to navigate from the *Organisation* to collection of connected *Country* entitities and also to inverse direction, you need bidirectional relationship between these two.

Nature of many-to-many relationship is optional. When you create new instance of *Country*, you are not forced to select *Organisation*(s). Model allows you to do so, but it is not obligatory. Both *Country* and *Organisation* can exist without any connected entities.